# Subversion & Xcode 4.3.1 -- SCM status letters all wrong?

Tags: svn, version-control, xcode4.3

All:

I checked out a repository, and when I open my working copy in Xcode, most of the files have an SCM code of A, which according to Apple's splendid documentation, means that have been locally added.  If I edit them, the SCM code stays at A, rather than M.  I can commit them, and the commits show up in the repo.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add something in subversion, *but do not commit*, then it will still be added status until you commit (no matter how many times you make changes). Also, the files will not be in the repository *until* the commit.

Once you have committed the files, any subsequent edits should then show as `M` (modified).

Comment: Thanks, @crashmstr -- but I checked it out _from_ a repository, so the files were already in it.  The repository did accidentally include a .git file, I wonder if that could have confused Xcode?

Comment: Ah, I misread what was happening. Have you tried looking at the status via command line svn?

Comment: I should have, as that would have been _extremely_ instructive.  Instead, but what I did instead was recreate the repo, check it out again, and now all is fine.  Thanks for your response and help!